# Make `npm install` dedupe (flatten) by default

Tags: node.js, npm

I made this sample directory example:

```
packages/
   package1/
     -- this has lodash as dependencies
   package2/
     -- this has package1 as dependencies using file:///path/to/packages/package1
```

When I do `npm install` inside `package2` my directory hierarchy is

```
package2/
  node_modules/
    package1/
      node_modules/
        lodash/
```

If I run `npm dedupe` after, then the directory becomes:

```
package2/
  node_modules/
    package1/
    lodash/
```

On the other hand, if I do `yarn install`, then I get the flattened directory by default. How can I make both `npm install` and `yarn install` behave the same? `npm dedupe` is *incredibly slow* and not practical in a real application.

This is more than just a matter of convenience - I currently have a `script` package and I want to move common dependencies into it. However, if the structure is not flattened, then if I do `require('some-package')` inside this `scripts` repo, I get module not found because the package is nested.

Answer (score 0):

Use `npm install --prefer-dedupe`

It will not always flatten the dependencies, flattening depends on the current state of your dependency tree.

Here is the documentation on it -> https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-dedupe